# Finding the center line and center point of rectangular region

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image

I ran the following code to create a rectangle contour:

```
#import the necessary packages
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2
import numpy as np

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
                help="path to the input image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load the image, convert it to grayscale, blur it slightly, and threshold it
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)

# threshold the image, then perform a series of erosions + dilations to remove any small regions of noise
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 45, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
thresh = cv2.erode(thresh, None, iterations=2)
thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=2)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Find the index of the largest contour
areas = [cv2.contourArea(c) for c in contours]
max_index = np.argmax(areas)
cnt=contours[max_index]

x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

# show the output image
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I would like to find the center line and center point of the rectangular contour. Please advise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you already have `(x, y, w, h)` of the desired contour using `x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)` in above code, so center of the vertical mid line can be given by `(x+w//2, y+h//2)` and vertical line can be drawn using below code:

```
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
# center line
cv2.line(image, (x+w//2, y), (x+w//2, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
# below circle to denote mid point of center line
center = (x+w//2, y+h//2)
radius = 2
cv2.circle(image, center, radius, (255, 255, 0), 2)
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome. I am glad I could help. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you already have the bounding box, you can use [`cv2.moments()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) to find the center coordinates. This gives us the *centroid* (i.e., the center (x, y)-coordinates of the object)

```
M = cv2.moments(cnt)
cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
```

The center point is simply `(cX, cY)` and you can draw this with `cv2.circle()`

```
cv2.circle(image, (cX, cY), 5, (36, 255, 12), -1)
```

Similarly, we can draw the center line using `cv2.line()` or Numpy slicing

```
cv2.line(image, (x + int(w/2), y), (x + int(w/2), y+h), (0, 0, 255), 3)
image[int(cY - h/2):int(cY+h/2), cX] = (0, 0, 255)
```

```
import imutils
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load the image, convert it to grayscale, blur it slightly, and threshold it
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)

# threshold the image, then perform a series of erosions + dilations to remove any small regions of noise
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 45, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
thresh = cv2.erode(thresh, None, iterations=2)
thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=2)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Find the index of the largest contour
areas = [cv2.contourArea(c) for c in contours]
max_index = np.argmax(areas)
cnt=contours[max_index]

x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

M = cv2.moments(cnt)

cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])

cv2.circle(image, (cX, cY), 5, (36, 255, 12), -1)

# To draw line you can use cv2.line or numpy slicing
cv2.line(image, (x + int(w/2), y), (x + int(w/2), y+h), (0, 0, 255), 3)
# image[int(cY - h/2):int(cY+h/2), cX] = (36, 255, 12)

# show the output image
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.imwrite("Image.png", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate it.

Comment: @dfahsjdahfsudaf No problem, glad I could help!